# ERROR: All dimension arguments must be greater than zero while startin parpool from Java

Tags: matlab, distributed-computing, matlabcontrol

If I run Matlab normally, then `gcp` command causes normal creation of parallel pool.

If I run the same Matlab from Java's `matlabcontrol`, then `gcp` command does not work with the following error:

```
>> gcp
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'InTheMoon' profile ... 
Error using parallel.internal.pool.PoolArrayManager.getOrAutoCreateWithCleanup (line 51)
Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile 'InTheMoon' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)

Error in gcp (line 33)
    aPool = parallel.internal.pool.PoolArrayManager.getOrAutoCreateWithCleanup();

Caused by:
    Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient/start (line 326)
    Failed to start pool.
        Error using parallel.Job/submit (line 304)
        All dimension arguments must be greater than zero

51                          throw(err);
```

The same error occurs if I do "validation" from cluster setup dialogs. No additional comprehensive information provided.

This is probably some path or configuration problem I don't understand.

Comment: Did you check your firewall setting? (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/104667-cannot-open-local-matlabpool)